# How do I read information from text files?

Tags: r, text-files, text-processing, logfile-analysis

I have hundreds of text files with the following information in each file:

```
*****Auto-Corelation Results******
1     .09    -.19     .18     non-Significant

*****STATISTICS FOR MANN-KENDELL TEST******
S=  609
VAR(S)=      162409.70
Z=           1.51
Random : No trend at 95%

*****SENs STATISTICS ******
SEN SLOPE =  .24
```

Now, I want to read all these files, and "collect" *Sen's Statistics* from each file (eg. `.24`) and compile into one file along with the corresponding file names. I have to do it in R.

I have worked with CSV files but not sure how to use text files.

This is the code I am using now:

```
require(gtools)
GG <- grep("*.txt", list.files(), value = TRUE)
GG<-mixedsort(GG)
S <- sapply(seq(GG), function(i){
X <- readLines(GG[i])
grep("SEN SLOPE", X, value = TRUE)
})
spl <- unlist(strsplit(S, ".*[^.0-9]"))
SenStat <- as.numeric(spl[nzchar(spl)])
SenStat<-data.frame( SenStat,file = GG)
write.table(SenStat, "sen.csv",sep = ", ",row.names = FALSE)
```

The current code is not able to read all values correctly and giving this error:

```
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Also I am not getting the file names the other column of Output. Please help!

---

## Diagnosis 1

The code is reading the = sign as well. This is the output of print(spl)

```
 [1] ""       "5.55"   ""       "-.18"   ""       "3.08"   ""       "3.05"   ""       "1.19"   ""       "-.32"  
[13] ""       ".22"    ""       "-.22"   ""       ".65"    ""       "1.64"   ""       "2.68"   ""       ".10"   
[25] ""       ".42"    ""       "-.44"   ""       ".49"    ""       "1.44"   ""       "=-1.07" ""       ".38"   
[37] ""       ".14"    ""       "=-2.33" ""       "4.76"   ""       ".45"    ""       ".02"    ""       "-.11"  
[49] ""       "=-2.64" ""       "-.63"   ""       "=-3.44" ""       "2.77"   ""       "2.35"   ""       "6.29"  
[61] ""       "1.20"   ""       "=-1.80" ""       "-.63"   ""       "5.83"   ""       "6.33"   ""       "5.42"  
[73] ""       ".72"    ""       "-.57"   ""       "3.52"   ""       "=-2.44" ""       "3.92"   ""       "1.99"  
[85] ""       ".77"    ""       "3.01"
```

## Diagnosis 2

Found the problem I think. The negative sign is a bit tricky. In some files it is

```
SEN SLOPE =-1.07
SEN SLOPE = -.11
```

Because of the gap after =, I am getting NAs for the first one, but the code is reading the second one. How can I modify the regex to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume `"text.txt"` is one of your text files.  Read into R with `readLines`, you can use `grep` to find the line containing `SEN SLOPE`.  With no further arguments, `grep` returns the index number(s) for the element where the regular expression was found. Here we find that it's the 11th line. Add the `value = TRUE` argument to get the line as it reads.

```
x <- readLines("text.txt")
grep("SEN SLOPE", x)
## [1] 11
( gg <- grep("SEN SLOPE", x, value = TRUE) )
## [1] "SEN SLOPE =  .24"
```

To find all the `.txt` files in the working directory we can  use `list.files` with a regular expression.

```
list.files(pattern = "*.txt")
## [1] "text.txt"
```

**LOOPING OVER MULTIPLE FILES**

I created a second text file, `text2.txt` with a different `SEN SLOPE` value to illustrate how I might apply this method over multiple files.  We can use `sapply`, followed by `strsplit`, to get the `spl` values that are desired.

```
GG <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt")
S <- sapply(seq_along(GG), function(i){
    X <- readLines(GG[i])
    ifelse(length(X) > 0, grep("SEN SLOPE", X, value = TRUE), NA)
    ## added 04/23/14 to account for empty files (as per comment)
})
spl <- unlist(strsplit(S, split = ".*((=|(\\s=))|(=\\s|\\s=\\s))"))
## above regex changed to capture up to and including "=" and 
## surrounding space, if any - 04/23/14 (as per comment)
SenStat <- as.numeric(spl[nzchar(spl)])
```

Then we can put the results into a data frame and send it to a file with `write.table`

```
( SenStatDf <- data.frame(SenStat, file = GG) )
##   SenStat      file
## 1    0.46 text2.txt
## 2    0.24  text.txt
```

We can write it to a file with

```
write.table(SenStatDf, "myFile.csv", sep = ", ", row.names = FALSE)
```

---

**UPDATED 07/21/2014:**

Since the result is being written to a file, this can be made much more simple (and faster) with

```
( SenStatDf <- cbind(
      SenSlope = c(lapply(GG, function(x){
          y <- readLines(x)
          z <- y[grepl("SEN SLOPE", y)]
          unlist(strsplit(z, split = ".*=\\s+"))[-1]
          }), recursive = TRUE),
      file = GG
 ) )
#      SenSlope file       
# [1,] ".46"   "test2.txt"
# [2,] ".24"   "test.txt"
```

And then written and read into R with

```
write.table(SenStatDf, "myFile.txt", row.names = FALSE)
read.table("myFile.txt", header = TRUE)
#   SenSlope      file
# 1     1.24 test2.txt
# 2     0.24  test.txt
```

Comment: Oops. Need some help. Some of the values are negative. And the code is reading them as positive. What change do I have to make to read them correctly?

Comment: The code was working before but I now I am suddenly seeing this error: Error in strsplit(S, ".*[^(-|\\s).0-9]") : non-character argument I am not sure what is going wrong. :-( Could you please help? Also, the expected values are between -5 and 5 @richard

Comment: Yes, same code, same place. :( Everything was working fine till few days back.

Comment: Hi Richard, the code is working now. But I am not getting the file names in column 2. And some NA values are getting added. Don't know why. Not reading all values. Out of 44 files in the first run, I couldn't read 5 values. I have added some diagnosis

Comment: Because there was a problem with the naming of the files. Could you please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160087/how-to-sort-alphabetically-in-r/23160208?noredirect=1#comment35416989_23160208

It shouldn't affect your code, I think.

Comment: Hurrah! It works. But the files names are still missing. Now I have all the values correctly.

Comment: Haha. Thanks. Hard to keep calm with project report due in two days. Did all the work and now I am stuck with sorting. Thanks!:P

Comment: Can you add a logic somewhere for this: I have found that it is again not working because sometimes one file is completely blank. I have manually found them. But how can I put that in that code? I will use your strsplit edit.

Answer (score 4):

First make a sample text file:

```
cat('*****Auto-Corelation Results******
1     .09    -.19     .18     non-Significant

*****STATISTICS FOR MANN-KENDELL TEST******
S=  609
VAR(S)=      162409.70
Z=           1.51
Random : No trend at 95%

*****SENs STATISTICS ******
SEN SLOPE =  .24',file='samp.txt')
```

Then read it in:

```
tf <- readLines('samp.txt')
```

Now extract the appropriate line:

```
sen_text <- grep('SEN SLOPE',tf,value=T)
```

And then get the value past the equals sign:

```
sen_value <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(sen_text,'='))[2])
```

Then combine these results for each of your files (no file structure mentioned in the original question)

Comment: This is exactly the same as my answer. :)

Comment: @RichardScriven Well, then you have a pretty good answer ;-) `readLines` is really cool.

Comment: Thank you. How do I add all the Sen values in a single dataframe in a loop? And then export it into a CSV file that basically has this format (filename,sen_value)

Comment: See @richardscriven 's answer above on how to loop through each text file

Answer (score 1):

If you're text files are always of that format, (eg Sen Slope is always on line 11) and the text is identical over all your files you can do what you need in just two lines.

```
char_vector <- readLines("Path/To/Document/sample.txt")
statistic <- as.numeric(strsplit(char_vector[11]," ")[[1]][5])
```

That will give you 0.24.

You then iterate over all your files via an apply statement or a for loop.

For clarity:

```
> char_vector[11]
[1] "SEN SLOPE =  .24"
```

and

```
> strsplit(char_vector[11]," ")
[[1]]
[1] "SEN"   "SLOPE" "="     ""      ".24"
```

Thus you want [[1]] [5] of the result from strsplit.

Answer (score 1):

Step1: Save complete `fileNames` in a single variable:

```
fileNames <- dir(dataDir,full.names=TRUE)
```

Step2: Lets read and process one of the files, and ensure that it is giving correct results:

```
data.frame(
  file=basename(fileNames[1]), 
  SEN.SLOPE= as.numeric(tail(
    strsplit(grep('SEN SLOPE',readLines(fileNames[1]),value=T),"=")[[1]],1))
  )
```

Step3: Do this on all the `fileNames`

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(fileNames, 
         function(fileName) data.frame(
           file=basename(fileName), 
           SEN.SLOPE= as.numeric(tail(
             strsplit(grep('SEN SLOPE',
                           readLines(fileName),value=T),"=")[[1]],1)
             )
           )
         )
  )
```

Hope this helps!!