# How to sort alphabetically in R?

Tags: r

My files are of the format:

```
ada1
ada2
ada3
....
ada10
ada11
ada12
```

Unfortunately, when I write out a10,a11 and a12 comes before a2. Could you help me sort it alphabetically as it should be?

#

Edit

Now, I have thousands of these files. Basically, xyz1-12, abc1-12 etc.

I use the following to get all files:

```
GG <- grep("*.txt", list.files(), value = TRUE)
```

So I can't put 'ada' manually.

Comment: Is it possible to rename the files in your example?

Comment: What you show is not alphabetical sorting. You can use `mixedsort` from package gtools.

Comment: I would prefer not to rename the actual files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using package `gtools`:

```
require(gtools)
x <- paste0('a', 1:12)
mixedsort(x)
[1] "a1"  "a2"  "a3"  "a4"  "a5"  "a6"  "a7"  "a8"  "a9"  "a10" "a11" "a12"
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added some info. I can't add a manually as I have thousands of files. How can I adapt your code?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just use `mixedsort(GG)`.

Comment: @GeekunaMatata  He simply created a set of "test" names. Just run `mixedsort` on your collection of file names.

Answer (score 3):

If there are always three characters, you can sort independently by those characters, followed by a numeric sort of the rest of the string:

```
GG <- paste0(c('ada', 'xyz'), 1:20) # Synthesis of data similar to what your command would give
```

Using `order` with multiple arguments gives the permutation of the vector, then indexing by that permutation returns the data in the desired sort order:

```
GG[order(substring(GG, 1, 3), as.numeric(substring(GG, 4)))]
 [1] "ada1"  "ada3"  "ada5"  "ada7"  "ada9"  "ada11" "ada13" "ada15" "ada17" "ada19" "xyz2"  "xyz4"  "xyz6"  "xyz8"  "xyz10"
[16] "xyz12" "xyz14" "xyz16" "xyz18" "xyz20"
```

Comment: I use GG <- grep("*.txt", list.files(), value = TRUE) to list the files in the folder. How can I "connect" it with your code instead of putting names manually? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please explain? I didn't get it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment.  I substituted `GG` in the expression.  It sounds like this is what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have explained properly. This is not what I was looking for. Basically, GG gives me the names of all the files in the folder, which I want to sort. I don't want to insert 'ada','xyz' manually like you have. How could I do it? Thanks

Comment: Thanks anyways. Mixed sort is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change their names to something better (that is ada001, ada002...) then you could create an double index. I am assuming `fnames` is a vector with the file names, and the numbers are only preceded by a fixed number of letters.

```
alpha <- substr(fnames, 1, 3)
num <- as.integer(substr(fnames, 4, nchar(fnames)))

o <- order(alpha, num)   ## that's your sorting vector
```

You can modify this procedure to accommodate a varying number of letters using regular expressions to find the split.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the file names you could do something like the following:

```
names0 <- paste0("a", 1:20)
temp <- strsplit(names0, "a")
ind <- sapply(temp, "[[", 2)
names1 <- paste0("a", sprintf("%03d", as.numeric(ind)))

> names1
[1] "a001" "a002" "a003" "a004" "a005" "a006"
[7] "a007" "a008" "a009" "a010" "a011" "a012"
[13] "a013" "a014" "a015" "a016" "a017" "a018"
[19] "a019" "a020"
```

You may have to tweak the call to `sprintf`, based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18360499/1623354).

Just to clarify, using `file.rename`, it would be pretty easy to rename all your files.